# how to compile a standard linux package (./configure; make; make install) for an ARM embedded linux environment

Tags: cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I already have a functional embedded linux system using MontaVista.  My embedded board boots linux and runs the included binaries just fine.  I know how to make a small C program and compile it with a `Makefile` that calls `arm_v5t_le-gcc` instead of `gcc`.

That is all simple enough, but how the heck do you configure and install a "standard" linux package that requires `./configure`, `make`, and `make install`?

The main conceptual problem I have is that `./configure` collects data about your current system like compilers and include files and such.  When I run `./configure`, it is just going to collect info about my desktop linux environment, not my embedded environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question.  It turns out you can run `./configure -h` to see some options, some of which allow you to describe your embedded (or cross compile) environment.

In my specific case, I wanted to compile libvisca (a Sony RS232 camera control library) for my embedded ARM environment that runs MontaVista.  I ran the following commands to get it working:

```
export CC=arm_v5t_le-gcc
export AR=arm_v5t_le-ar

./configure --host=arm

make
```

So long as you have the above compilers in your `$PATH`, you're all set.  Happy compiling.